# Text-based way to set parts of audio track that play and skip

Tags: audio, sound-editing, clipping, audio-editor

I am looking for a text-based way to set various start and end points within a given audio file, so that whenever an end point is reached, the audio file skips to the next start point when playing. (I think the example I have below will make what I am looking for more clear.)

The closest thing that I have found to what I am looking for is a cue file, but as far as I can tell, that is intended purely to label different segments of an audio file as different tracks.

So for example, here is a cue file I have:

```
PERFORMER "Unknown Artist"
TITLE "Unknown Title"
FILE "File.mp3" WAVE
TRACK 01 AUDIO
TITLE "Track01"
PERFORMER "Unknown Artist"
INDEX 01 00:10:00
TRACK 02 AUDIO
TITLE "Track02"
PERFORMER "Unknown Artist"
INDEX 01 01:15:00
```

This file will start playback at `00:10:00`, then just continue playing. At `01:15:00`, it will change the label of what is being played. What I want is something more like what the following fake cue file would do:

```
PERFORMER "Unknown Artist"
TITLE "Unknown Title"
FILE "File.mp3" WAVE
TRACK 01 AUDIO
TITLE "Track01"
PERFORMER "Unknown Artist"
INDEX 01 00:10:00 00:30:00
TRACK 02 AUDIO
TITLE "Track02"
PERFORMER "Unknown Artist"
INDEX 01 01:15:00 01:30:00
```

The idea is that, when using this, the audio file would play from `00:10:00` to `00:30:00`, then jump to `01:15:00` and continue playing until `01:30:00`.

Does anyone know of a tool where I can implement this kind of thing (or if I can do it with cue files, does anyone know how)?

By the way, I know this is probably an obscure request. The purpose behind it is to have an easy way to do rough cuts of audio tracks where I have a lot of stuff I want to get rid of. For me, a text-based way like this to do this would be easier to use than a lot of the free point-and-click based tools, like Audacity.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the command-line utility [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). The 'trim' effect might be suitable for your use case.